# R: why am I not getting the function to return the vector as intended?

Tags: r, for-loop, return

```
    corr <- function(directory, threshold) { 
          files <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
          nu <- numeric()
          for(i in length(files)) {
            my_data <- read.csv(files[i])
            if (sum(complete.cases(my_data)) >= threshold) {
              vec_sul <- my_data[complete.cases(my_data),]$sulfate
              vec_nit <- my_data[complete.cases(my_data),]$nitrate
              nu <- c(nu, cor(vec_sul, vec_nit))
            }
          }
      nu
    }
```

I've a list of .csv files sitting inside the directory I wish to pass as an argument to the function illustrated above. I also pass threshold value as the second argument. The objective is to read through all the files in the directory parameter and check if the files have complete cases more than the threshold value passed as the second arg.

Those files that pass this criteria will further be examined and follows the evaluation of the correlation between the two variables inside it: Sulfate and Nitrate. The series of such correlation values associated with the files that have more complete cases than the threshold value will be concatenated to a numerical variable vector. At the end of the loop execution, I want the function to return the vector containing the series of the correlation values evaluated in the "if" loop.

cr <- corr("specdata", 150)
When I run the above line of code in console, I get a numerical variable which is null. Could someone help me fix the code?

Comment: Two problems. 1) the 'nu' on hte RHS of that assignment is probably meant to be an "i" and 2) as it is , you are only going to see the last one because you are not using an index for "nu" (and possibly a third since the best way to do this would not using a numeric vector for this... list or would be better. A fourth problem is that students in Peng's R course are supposed to be using the website help facilities provided by the course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this kind of error has been seen so many times, it still happen. You want

```
i in 1:length(files)
```

You get `numeric(0)` (the "numeric null" you talk about), because your loop only reads in the final file. I guess the final file does not satisfy `sum(complete.cases(my_data)) >= threshold` so nothing is added to `nu`, initialized as `numeric(0)`.

---

Also, I would like to point out that

```
vec_sul <- my_data[complete.cases(my_data),]$sulfate
vec_nit <- my_data[complete.cases(my_data),]$nitrate
nu <- c(nu, cor(vec_sul, vec_nit))
```

can be replaced by

```
nu <- c(nu, with(my_data, cor(sulfate, nitrate, use = "complete.obs")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vectorized `lapply()` across list of files which avoids expanding a preset vector. The only adjustment is that lapply will return a length equal to input list, `files`, hence an `else` statement is added to fill in for dataframes with unmet threshold condition. But outside the loop, `nu` is removed of these NAs.

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold) { 

           files <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
           nu <- lapply(files, function(i) {
               my_data <- read.csv(i)
               if (sum(complete.cases(my_data)) >= threshold) {
                   vec_sul <- my_data[complete.cases(my_data),]$sulfate
                   vec_nit <- my_data[complete.cases(my_data),]$nitrate
                   temp <- cor(vec_sul, vec_nit)
               } else {
                   temp <- NA           # SET NAs   
               }
               return(temp)
           })

       nu <- nu[!is.na(nu)]             # REMOVE NAs
       return(nu)
}
```

Alternatively, try even `vapply()` (arguably slightly faster) to specify a numeric vector return

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold) { 

           files <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)          
           nu <- vapply(files, function(i) {
               my_data <- read.csv(i)
               if (sum(complete.cases(my_data)) >= threshold) {
                   vec_sul <- my_data[complete.cases(my_data),]$sulfate
                   vec_nit <- my_data[complete.cases(my_data),]$nitrate
                   temp <- cor(vec_sul, vec_nit)
               } else {
                   temp <- NA           # SET NAs    
               }
               return(temp)
           }, numeric(1))          

       nu <- nu[!is.na(nu)]             # REMOVE NAs
       return(nu)
}
```